# How to print a subtree of a binary tree?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, subtree

In my program, I have initialized a binary tree and I want to search if a node exists in that binary tree. If it does exist, then I will print the subtree of that node and the level it was found. I am able to perform my `search` method but I am not sure **how to print the subtree of that node found and its level**.

For example, this is my binary tree `[K=3 L=[K=1 R=[K=2]] R=[K=5 L=[K=4]]`. If I search for node `1`, then it will return the node (not null) since it exists in my binary tree.

> **Problem:** I need to print only the subtree of the node and the level where it was found: `[K=1 R=[K=2]], level=1`.

Here is my source code for reference:

**Main Class**

```
// instantiate BST object
BST<Character> bst = new BST<>(); 

// insert values to bst1
String str = "31254";
char[] letter = str.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
    Character c = letter[i];

    bst1.insert(c);
}

// print bst
System.out.println("\nht=" + bst1.height + " " + bst1.toString() + "\n");

// search values in bst1
String str2 = "016483"; 
char[] letter2 = str2.toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < letter2.length; i++) {
    Character c = letter2[i];
    
    if (bst1.search(c) != null) { // if found, print the node (w/ subtree) and its level
        // ** part that should print the subtree and its level
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(c + " is not found.");
    }
}
```

**BST Class** - where my `search` method is declared

```
public class BST<T extends Comparable<T>> extends BT<T> {
    // insert() method

    // search method
    public BTNode<T> search(T k) {// my method
        
            BTNode<T> n = root;
            
            while (n != null) {
                if (n.info.compareTo(k) == 0)  {
                    return n;
                }
                else {
                    if (n.info.compareTo(k) > 0) {
                        n = n.left;
                    }
                    else {
                        n = n.right;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Conceptually the same way you print the whole tree. You can print using [inorder, preorder or postorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). A recursive implementation is very simple. Iterative traversal is a bit more involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not modify your code. Instead, I used an imaginary class Node that I've written. Also, I have written all of them as **half pseudo half java code**.
Suppose your node has only one int type variable and two children.

```
class Node{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
}
```

You have a `printExistingSubTree` method in your BST class that does the what you exactly ask for:

```
printExistingSubTree(Node node, int key):
    if (find(node.left, key, 0) != -1)
        then 
            printTree(node.left)
            print(find(node.left, key, 0))
    if (find(node.right, key, 0) != -1)
        then printTree(node.right)
            printTree(node.right)
            print(find(node.right, key, 0))
```

You have a `find` method in your BST class that does find the index:

```
int find(Node node,int key, int level)
    if(node.data is equal to the key)
        then return level
    int left = -1;
    
    if(node.leftChild is not null)
        then left = find(node.left, key, level+1)
    if(left != -1)
        return left
    int right = -1;
    if(node.rightChild is not null)
        then right = find(node.right, key, level+1)
    return right
```

Then, to print, you should decide how you want to traverse the subtree.

You have a `printTree` method in your BST class that prints the subtree in **postorder**:

```
void printTree(Node node){
    if (node == null)
        return;
     printTree(node.left);
 
     printTree(node.right);
 
     print(node.data + " ");
}
```

Note: I did not understand your whole code. Therefore, I have just written the answer of your question in the pseudo code format. I think, you can write your own code from that.

Note2: There may be some typos&wrong namings. PLease do not lynch. Just write in the comments and I'll correct.

Comment: My class BTNode<T> is a generic class, should I change part of the code you have given? Thanks for your detailed answer!

Comment: You can use a template class. I just used int for simplicity. You can use Node your class T instead of int here. I'm not sure whether I could understand what you mean by "change part of the code you have given". If you mean you should not use template class, no, you can use of course. By the way, I may recommend you to use a **comparator** for simplicity.